# Using offline storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, offline-browsing

I am trying to make a website which will store all the contacts of the user on the server database. The user can add, edit, delete or update a contact. I want the user to be able to do all these functionality even when he is offline. What should I use to achieve this. I came across web sql database  which can be use to store database offline. But I dont know how to synchronise the online and offline database. I am using Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 1):

According to Web SQL's W3C page, the specification is no longer in active maintenance and the Web Applications Working Group does not intend to maintain it further (http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/).

Why don't you give HTML5's persistent storage a try instead? There's a great tutorial [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) that also features a chapter on local storage hacks before HTML5, so you may read it if you're not planning to dive into HTML5 just yet.

You may also try [Google Gears](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/), as it features an interface to a local sqlite3 database in which you may store your offline data.

As for the synchronization mechanism try [persistanceJS](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs). It should help you with both HTML5 and Google Gears options.

**EDIT**

Apparently persistanceJS has no support for rails just yet, but there's a tutorial on how to use local HTML5 storage with rails [here](http://nithinbekal.com/2010/a-simple-to-do-list-app-using-html5-and-local-storage/), and there's a rails plugin to easily enable gears on rails apps [here](http://code.google.com/p/gearsonrails/). Those should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby on Rails to do it as well.  Check out the Railscast series of video tutorials.  Specifically [episode 247](http://railscasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1) to get started with ROR and offline storage